# Для чего нужны свойства?

Tags: c#, c#-faq

Допустим есть это:

```
private int a { get; set; }
```

Какой в этом смысл, если я могу сделать так:

```
public int a;
```

Comment: свойсвта можно определять в интерфейсе, а поля - нет

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/

Comment: Вопрос скорее звучит как "Для чего нужна инкапсуляция в ООП?"

Comment: Есть библиотеки, для работами с которыми ваш класс должен содержать *свойство*, например EntityFramework.

Answer (score 404, accepted):

Смотрите, какие есть преимущества у свойства перед полем.

Если ваше свойство определено так:

```
public int A { get; set; }
```

— то непосредственных выгод, конечно, нету. Но выгоды придут позже.

1. Вы можете навесить свою логику на запись и считывание значения. Применений может быть море. Например, вы хотите посчитать, сколько раз считывалось значение:

   ```
   private int a;
   private int readcount_a = 0;
   public int A
   {
       get { readcount_a++; return a; }
       set { a = value; }
   }
   ```

   Вы можете сделать триггер на изменение поля:

   ```
   class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       private int a;
       public int A
       {
           get { return a; }
           set
           {
               if (a == value)
                    return;
               a = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged();
           }
       }

       private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
       {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
   }
   ```

   Вы можете залогировать все изменения поля:

   ```
   public int A
   {
       get { return a; }
       set
       {
           Trace.TraceInformation("Changing value of a from {0} to {1}", a, value);
           a = value;
       }
   }
   ```

   Вы можете навесить проверку значения на корректность при записи, или ленивую инициализацию при чтении.

   ```
   class Data
   {
       private string a = null;
       public string A
       {
           get
           {
               return a ?? (a = LazyComputeInitialA());
           }
           set
           {
               if (value == null)
                   throw new ArgumentException(nameof(A) + " cannot be null", nameof(A));
               a = value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   В конце-концов, вы можете не расходовать память на значение, если в большинстве случаев оно одинаковое (как это сделано у `DependencyProperty`):

   ```
   class Data
   {
       static Dictionary<Data, int> aValues = new Dictionary<Data, int>();

       public int A
       {
           get
           {
               int result;
               if (aValues.TryGetValue(this, out result))
                   return result;
               else
                   return -1; // default value
           }
           set
           {
                aValues[this] = value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   [Если вы захотите воспользоваться этим кодом в своём проекте, применяйте улучшенный вариант[:](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/112#issuecomment-71876402)

   ```
   static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<Data, StrongBox<int>> aValues =
                                     new ConditionalWeakTable<Data, StrongBox<int>>();

   public int A
   {
       get => aValues.TryGetValue(this, out var tmp) ? tmp.Value : -1; // default value
       set => aValues.GetOrCreateValue(this).Value = value;
   }
   ```

   В этом варианте исправлены недостатки варианта с `Dictionary`: в словаре более не хранится ссылка на объект `Data` (она препятствует удалению объекта сборщиком мусора), а также одновременный доступ из разных потоков не приведёт к проблемам с `Dictionary`, т. к. `ConditionalWeakTable` потокобезопасен.]
2. Вы хотите сделать разную степень видимости у геттера и сеттера, так что например только ваш класс и его наследники смогут установить значение, а считать смогут все. (Это, пожалуй, самое лучшее применение свойств, на мой вкус.)

   ```
   public int A { get; protected set; }
   ```
3. Вы можете вообще не определять setter, и возвращать какую-то высчитанную вами величину:

   ```
   public int A
   {
       get { return b + c; }
   }
   ```

   (впрочем, такое можно сделать и при наличии сеттера). Например, вы можете предоставлять данные в разных форматах:

   ```
   public double Radians { get; set; }
   public double Degrees
   {
       get { return Radians * 180.0 / Math.PI; }
       set { Radians = value * Math.PI / 180.0; }
   }
   ```
4. Вы можете установить брейкпойнт на запись или чтение свойства! Брейкпойнты на запись или чтение *данных* в отладчике управляемого кода Visual Studio пока (по крайней мере до текущей на данный момент версии Visual Studio 2017, версия 15.7) не поддерживаются. **Обновление**: начиная с .NET Core 3.0, брейкпойнты на изменение данных [поддерживаются](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019#BKMK_set_a_data_breakpoint_managed)!
5. Вы можете задать наличие свойства в интерфейсе, в отличие от поля:

   ```
   interface ISupportsA
   {
       int A { get; }
   }

   class Data : ISupportsA
   {
       public int A { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Если вы применяете [реализацию методов в интерфейсах](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/default-interface-methods-versions), появившуюся в C# 8, вы сможете реализовать свойство, используя технику с `ConditionalWeakTable`, описанную выше. Также при помощи этой техники вы сможете [добавить в класс данные в методах расширения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34976295/276994).
6. Вы можете объявить свойство виртуальным! То есть вы сможете переопределить поведение свойства в классах-наследниках. Попробуйте-ка сделать такое с полем.
7. Свойства *не хуже* полей в том смысле, что вы можете заставить свойство работать так, будет это просто поле (`public int A { get; set; }`), но вы не сможете поле заставить работать как свойство. То есть практически всегда лучше «наружу» выставлять свойство, а не поле.
8. <s>XML-сериализация и</s> WPF-овский `Binding` работает лишь со свойствами, но не с полями. Да, это можно считать ошибкой во фреймворке, но фактически это так.

---

Но не излишни ли свойства в языке? Кажется, что вместо свойства можно определить просто две функции:

```
class Data
{
    private int a;
    public int GetA() { return a; }
    public int SetA(int a) { this.a = a; }
}
```

Ответ на это таков.

Во-первых, одно свойство вместо двух функций представляет собой логическую группу. В хорошем языке вы говорите то, что думаете. На самом деле вы предоставляете пользователю «переменную» `A` с дополнительной, часто невидимой снаружи семантикой. Значит, и выглядеть она должна как одна переменная, чтобы пользователи класса думали в тех же терминах, что и вы.

Во-вторых, это читаемость текста. Сравните код со свойствами:

```
player.car.speed++;
```

и без них:

```
getPlayer().getCar().setSpeed(getPlayer().getCar().getSpeed()+1);
```

Что легче воспринимается?

---

Справедливости ради, нужно отметить и недостатки свойств по сравнению с полями.

1. Свойства нельзя использовать как `out`/`ref`-параметр, поля можно.
2. Доступ к полям очень быстр, а вот доступ к свойствам может быть медленным, если код внутри геттера/сеттера медленный. Однако, медленный сеттер или (ещё хуже) геттер считаются порочной практикой, их рекомендуется избегать, чтобы не разрушать ментальную модель «переменная с небольшим довеском».
3. Доступ к свойству может выбросить исключение или зависнуть, в то время как более простые поля ведут себя крайне просто. Конечно, правильно написанное свойство не будет зависать, а исключения я бы порекомендовал выбрасывать только в случаях, когда пользователь класса нарушил контракт на доступ к полю.

---

Ещё одно тонкое отличие свойства от поля состоит в том, что геттер возвращает вам *копию* значения, в то время как при работе с полем вы получаете доступ непосредственно к переменной. При работе со полями reference-типов (то есть, тип которых есть класс) практической разницы нет, так как работа с объектом по копии ссылки не отличается от работы по оригиналу ссылки. Разница, однако, есть, когда поле является *изменяемой* структурой (хотя, сами по себе изменяемые структуры — [плохая идея](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/mutating-readonly-structs)). Пример случая, когда это важно, во фрагменте кода ниже.

---

Часто считают, что можно для начала объявить данные как поле, а потом, при необходимости, «превратить» его в свойство. Это [лишь отчасти верно](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/PropertiesMatter): при этом вы теряете бинарную совместимость. Код, который использовал ваш класс, *должен* быть перекомпилирован, так как на уровне скомпилированного кода обращение к полю и к свойству — не одно и то же. Кроме того, смысл кода может поменяться, приводя к тонким ошибками. Пример из статьи по ссылке выше:

```
using System;

struct MutableStruct
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public void SetValue(int newValue) { Value = newValue; }
}

class MutableStructHolder
{
    public MutableStruct Field;
    public MutableStruct Property { get; set; }
}

class Test
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MutableStructHolder holder = new MutableStructHolder();
        // Меняет значение holder.Field
        holder.Field.SetValue(10);
        // Получает *копию* holder.Property и изменяет её
        holder.Property.SetValue(10);
        
        Console.WriteLine(holder.Field.Value);    // 10
        Console.WriteLine(holder.Property.Value); // 0
    }
}
```

---

Кстати, согласно [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#.D0.9C.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.8B_.D1.81.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2), геттер и сеттер правильно называть *акцессор* и *мутатор* соответственно. Вы об этом знали? [Хотя, MSDN пишет просто «[методы доступа](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)».]

Comment: "непосредственных выгод, конечно, нету..." - это не совсем верно. Вспомните хотя бы XAML-байндинги в WPF/Silverlight/и т.д.,  которые полей не признают, зато со свойствами работают.

Comment: @Mints97: Это пункт 8 ответа :-)

Comment: @VladD: простите, как-то проглядел =)

Comment: А согласно msdn, оба метода называются акцессорами. Или, по-русски, методами доступа. Кстати, в Википедии нет ссылки на источник...

Comment: @PavelMayorov: В английской сказано то же самое (хотя, конечно, это не означает автоматически, что в русской принято то же самое). В любом случаем все говорят просто «сеттер», на моей памяти. На MSDN в «ручном» переводе вместо этого пишут «_[метод доступа](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)_».

Comment: Я бы добавил, что у компонентов в дизайнере видны свойства, а поля нет.

Comment: @VladD `Ещё одно тонкое отличие свойства от поля состоит в том, что геттер возвращает вам копию значения, в то время как при работе со свойством вы получаете доступ непосредственно к переменной. ` опечатка.

Comment: @sp7: Точно! Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: @VladD, "Класс `XmlSerializer` способен сериализировать типы, не имеющие ни одного атрибута. По умолчанию он сериализирует _все открытые поля и свойства_ типа."

Comment: @Андрей: Хм, перепроверю дома. Вроде ж не умел?

Comment: @VladD, да не, всегда умел, даже в MSDN написано: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bdxxw552(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Андрей: И правда! Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Решили ещё баллов поднять на супер-ответе? :)

Comment: @Aid: Исправил баг :) Все ходы записаны же, и даже комментарий с багрепортом был сегодня.

Comment: Одно другому не мешает.

Comment: "Брейкпойнты на запись или чтение данных в отладчике .NET пока не поддерживаются." Было бы неплохо тут уточнить для какой версии отладчика они не поддерживаются.

Comment: @Anamnian: Насколько я понимаю, это так для всех версий вплоть до текущей. Но да, вы правы, дополню ответ.

Comment: Можно также отметить инкапсуляцию

Comment: @Viewed: Вы правы, по сути многие из перечисленных примеров (пункты 1 и 3) и являются примером инкапсуляции.

Comment: сообщение с самым большим рейтингом на всем ruSo!

Comment: Слышь, мужик, негр у тебя родился - мутатор мыть надо!

Answer (score 39):

Я думаю, что use-case'ов, в которых полезно делать именно поле, довольно таки много. Попробую привести вам один пример, поясняющий мотивацию использования свойства вместо поля.

Представим, что вы разрабатываете библиотеку классов. И реализовали класс как-то так:

```
class SuperClass
{
    public int a; // То есть, решили, что поля достаточно.
}
```

Вашей библиотекой пользуются другие разработчики (то есть, клиенты по отношению к вашему коду). И вот оказывается, что вы хотите добавить некую логику чтения или записи `a` (например, считывание значения из конфига). Полем здесь не обойдешься - делаем свойство:

```
class SuperClass
{
    public int a { get { /*какая-то логика*/ } set { /*какая-то логика*/ } }
}
```

Вы поставили библиотеку клиентам и оп-па... Их код больше не работает с вашим. Они не могут просто поставить обновление в виде вашей библиотеки, им придется пересобрать свои приложения, потому что поля `a` больше нет. Есть свойство, но не поле - внешний интерфейс класса изменился.

Код постоянно меняется, везде потенциально может появиться новая логика. Описанного неудобства не случилось бы, если бы вы сразу объявили свойство.

Общий смысл примерно таков: используйте свойства даже когда это просто запись и чтение из поля, тогда внешний интерфейс класса не изменится, даже если вы измените логику работы с этим полем.

Answer (score 16):

Использование свойства вместо поля является реализацией принципа инкапсуляции - одного из принципов объектно ориентированого программирования.

Comment: А чо собственно заминусовали?

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 а какое отношение имеет инкапсуляция к написанию `{ get; set; }`?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, прямое

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если углубится в ОПП, то согласно [принципу инкапсуляции](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) поля классов **всегда должны быть только приватными**. А вот для доступа к ним используются функции получения и установки значения. Свойства С#, это своего рода синтаксический сахар, что бы не прописывать функции аксессоры(accessors functions) каждый раз, за Вас это сделает компилятор. Вот если бы вы писали на С++/Java по всем правилам, то на каждое свойство создавали бы свои две функции установки/получения значения и никаких public полей.

Comment: @AlexKrass чаще всего такую вещь как `{ get; set; }` можно увидеть в DTO, а DTO не является классом в понимании ООП. Кроме того, есть мнение, что конструкция `{ get; set; }` нарушает инкапсуляцию столь же качественно, как и открытое свойство.

Answer (score 6):

Плюсов очень много.
Но важен тот, который  приносит пользу в нужный момент.
Эта вещь мне принесла пользу.
Был класс, ну допустим с A. Этот класс использовали из кучи мест. Даже не знаешь из каких. А обновить надо сейчас, через 15 минут. Поиск использования показывается 1100 позиций, а надо поменять только там, где в него что-то пишем.

Делаем из `public int A;` ->

```
public int A {get; private set;}
```

И любое присвоение выпадет списком ошибок.

Comment: И как это решит проблему,если бы стояло авто-свойство до этого? Чтобы поменялось в этих 1100 позиций использования?

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к подробнейшему ответу @VladD
Еще удобно инициализировать:

```
class Filter {
     public int ID { get; set;}
     public string Name { get; set;}
}

Filter filter = new Filter { ID = 15, Name = "Vasya" };
```

Comment: С полями такого нельзя повернуть? Ответ – можно: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers читаем первое предложение

Answer (score 4):

смысл есть, если связываешь скрипты к примеру или хочешь видеть значение в инспекторе, если приват-не видно паблик-видно

Comment: Причем здесь вообще Unity?