# Getter для public static final (java). Есть ли смысл?

Tags: java

Имеет ли смысл скрывать public static final константы и делать геттер либо нет?

Вышел небольшой спор... Спасибо! :)

Comment: вот такие вот вопросы и затевают нешуточные холивары в инете...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Универсальное правило ровно одно: следуйте семантике, смыслу кода.

Если вы экспортируете *константу*, смело выставляйте наружу `public static final`. Например:

```
class GlobalConstants
{
    public static final int DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7;
}
```

Если же вы экспортируете что-то, за чем есть или *может быть* логика, что *может* поменяться, сделайте это лучше свойством, чтобы потом можно было безболезненно для клиентов вашего кода эту логику поменять.

```
class MyCar
{
    private static final String manufacturerName = "ЗАЗ";
    public String getManufacturer()
    {
        return manufacturerName;
    }
}
```

Если завтра вы пересядете на "Феррари", у клиентов, которые скомпилировались со старой версией вашей библиотеки, не будет проблем. (А вот если бы ваша строка была константой, она оказалась бы жёстко вкомпилированной в код клиентов, и они бы продолжали считать, что вы ездите на "Запорожце".)

---

Подобный вопрос для C# уже [обсуждался на сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197067/).

Comment: вы должно быть имели в виду:

    public static final int DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7;

Comment: @jmu: угу, вы правы, заменю, спасибо. Java не мой родной язык.

Answer (score 1):

Нет никакого смысла. Поле то никак не поменяется - оно же final. Оно public - то есть уже доступное. Более того, вносить дополнительную прослойку - это только для адептов полного ООП.

Если не согласны, то подумайте над вопросом - а следует ли делать для этих полей setter'ы  (это вопрос с большой долей иронии).

Answer (score 1):

Я понимаю вопрос так: имеет ли смысл скрывать `static final`, ибо скрывать `public static final` нет никакого смысла - это точно.

В этом контексте я бы сказал, что да, иногда имеет смысл скрывать. Допустим есть ситуация где есть некая константа которая используется только в текущем классе и за его пределами она мало кому интересна. Далеко ходить не будем и приведу пример из реальной жизни:

Есть серия классов (иерархия), где каждый из классов оперирует понятием размер блока (речь идет о блочном шифровании). Коню понятно, что размер блока зависит от алгоритма шифрования, скажем для [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) это 64 бит, для [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) бывает и 128 и 256.

Вот тут-то и начинается самое интересное. Размер блока нужен внешней процедуре (функции) для того, чтобы понимать правила выравнивания блоков (padding) и проч. шифровальной муйне. Соответственно, нужен очевидно, геттер размера блока. Скажем для AES размер блока может быть любым между 128 и 256 (но кратно 32), а вот для DES он всегда константа и равно 64.

Ну и получится что-то типа:

```
abstract class Cipher {

   abstract public getBlockSize();
}

class CipherDES extends Cipher {
   private static final int BLOCK_SIZE=64;

   @Override
   public int getBlockSize() {return BLOCK_SIZE;}
}

class CipherAES extends Cipher {
   private int blockSize;

   @Override
   public int getBlockSize() {return blockSize;}
}
```

Жизнь многогранна и бывает всякое. Так что не торопитесь с выводами даже в очевидных ситуациях.

Comment: если оно private - то кто же спорит. Вопрос был о public.

В приведенном Вами коде это уже не совсем геттер. Да, он выглядит как геттер, но таковым не является.

Comment: Ну дисклеймер я в самом начале писал. И, кстати, от того что константа будет `public` ничего не меняется - типа геттера все равно понадобится

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется это из разряда "на вкус и цвет товарища нет"... 
Но я бы сделал геттеры.)

Comment: геттер для константы? а смысл?

Comment: @Gorets, я же сказал, что ответ на этот вопрос у каждого свой         
Если ты не можешь без полного ооп, то напишешь геттер, если более простой парень, то не будешь писать)

Comment: @KoVadim вот он аргументировал достаточно хорошо, можно константы в блокноте хранить и через энум делать, но это не просто "способ - как нравится, так и делай", это просто тупо