# Зачем нужны getter and setter методы?

Tags: ооп, setter, инкапсуляция, getter

Давно уже пишу на java и я привык свойства класса делать приватном и писать для них гетер и сетер методы но я понял что не знаю зачем это нужно? Ведь если у тебя есть метод сетер и гетер к свойству не легче сделать его публичном и использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас действительно никакой логики в геттерах сеттерах нет (и не предвидится), а только "пустышки", то вы только захламляете код лишними методами. Вспомните YAGNI - то что вы планируете может вам никогда не понадобится, но вы уже платите цену за возросшую сложность кода.

То что что-то *можно* использовать, не значит что это *будет* использовано. А то можно сразу и историю к каждому полю прицепить, и стэк, и логгирование .. но обычно не нужно.

Если же в геттерах-сеттерах чаще есть логика (примеры такой логики приведены в других ответах), чем ее нет, то да, код будет конситентнее (проще), если писать их везде по единому шаблону.

---

Аналогичный вопрос про C++ - [В чем смысл геттеров и сеттеров в C++ (и не только)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448423)

Answer (score 2):

Методы get() и set() нужны не только для того, чтобы получить доступ к данным, но и чтобы не допустить некорректной работы с ними.

Например:

```
private int n = 1; 
int[] array = new int[5];

public void setN(int n) {
    if (n >= 0 && n < 5)
        this.n = n;
    else 
        this.n = 2;
{ 

public void method() {
    array[this.n] = 5;
}
```

В данном случае, если мы захотим изменить n вызвав метод setN(), то при вызове метода method(), не будет ошибки из-за выхода за пределы массива.