# Static или Private

Tags: c++, c, ооп

Я большой фанат C, и не совсем понимаю, зачем нам использовать private методы? Делать для них геттеры и сеттеры, и остальные абсолютно(по-моему мнению) не нужные вещи. Почему бы не сделать static для функции(для сокрытия вне данного translation unit), и все намного элегантнее и без синтаксического сахара?

P.S. Я новичок, сильно не ругайтесь.

Comment: Вам знакомо понятие инкапсуляция?

Comment: Да, но си в тоже есть инкапсуляция.

Comment: Вы говорите об очень простых структурах, но   классы инкапсулируют свои данные, чтобы внутреннее представление  нельзя было трограть извне, иначе могут испортить обьект. И много других причин...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну если использовать static, вне translation unit'а их и нельзя будет потрограть.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Я не понял, что вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: Вы случаем не путаете спецификаторы хранения `static` и спецификаторы статичности методов `static` и спецификаторы доступа? Вы случаем не путаете методы с полями? Зачем делать геттеры для методов? Неужели в С вас не напрягала необходимость делать дополнительные единицы трасляции для сокрытия или неполное сокрытие при отсутствии таких доп. единиц?

Comment: Я не смогу обьяснить коротко,  но двумя словами ООП этим и отличается от структурного программирования. Геттеры далеко не всегда  нужны и далеко не всегда разрешают доступ ко всем закрытым данным

Comment: @VTT Я имею в виду именно спецификатор хранения. А зачем делать сокрытие в том же TU? Как я понял, геттеры и сеттеры помогают выстроить граммотный API для метода(Если я правильно описал). Недавно наткнулся на это видео, и он полностью отражает мои мысли(может так станет ясно, что я имею ввиду) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xLgr6Ng4qQ

Comment: Читайте:   Гради Буч  "Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование"  второе издание.

Comment: А как по-вашему соотносятся спецификатор хранения и спецификатор доступа? Они же не являются альтарнативами друг другу, они ведь даже не могут быть применимы к одной и той же сущности. И при чем тут геттеры и сеттеры (которые никак не связаны ни со спецификаторами хранения, ни со спецификаторами доступа)? Человека на видео по ссылке я не могу охарактеризовать иначе как "воинственный говнокодер", он прямо вещает, что не умеет использовать классы и не понимает для чего нужны геттеры, а в конце выдает предложение переименовать переменную чтобы сломать билд и потом править места с ошибками...

Comment: *"геттеры и сеттеры помогают выстроить граммотный API для метода"* Еще раз, вы не путаете поля и методы?

Comment: Вы на правильном пути, здраво глядите на вещи, и не одиноки в этом -- [“Object-oriented programming is an exceptionally bad idea which could only have originated in California.” – Edsger Dijkstra](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/OO_programming/)

Comment: @VTT Хорошо, спрошу по-другому: почему нельзя просто всегда использовать private?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду `private` для полей? Просто вариант с `private` для вообще всего не будет жизнеспособен.

Comment: @VTT извиняюсь, хотел написать public. Да, для полей.

Comment: Наверное вам стоит ознакомиться с [В чем смысл геттеров и сеттеров в C++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448423/В-чем-смысл-геттеров-и-сеттеров-в-c-и-не-только)

Comment: @kaylil_01, вы думаете как си программист, и вам кажется все удручающе. Прочитайте хотя бы про принципы ООП, и вам станет немного легче все это воспринимать. Вы начнете понимать что такое разделение обязанностей, и почему есть закрытые поля, почему не стоит почти никогда использовать геттеры, сеттеры.

Answer (score 1):

private нужны для запрета вызова методов и обращения к переменным из этой секции. Допустим, ваш класс занимается рисованием прямоугольников. Естественно, вы рисуете прямоугольник линиями. Вы определите соответствующий метод. И логически верно его будет скрыть из публичных методов как минимум потому что рисовать линии при помощи объекта, рисующего прямоугольники выглядит, гм, глупо наверное.

static жэ это немножко про другое. Это когда нужно вызывать метод класса без необходимости создавать экземпляр этого класса.

Ну и синтаксический сахар - это как правило хорошо.

Comment: "немножко про другое" - ??

Comment: Это такой оборот речи :)

Comment: Мы разные вещи под static'ом подразумеваем, вы имеете в виду статик для класса, а я для функции или для переменной, это же разные вещи.