# Поля vs автоматически реализуемый свойства

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Всем привет,

Изучаю C#, в процессе задался вопросом, который никак не могу разрешить.

Поле:

```
string Name;
```

Автоматически реализуемое свойство:`

```
string Name { get; set; }
```

Что такое свойства, зачем они нужны и как работают я, конечно понял. Но хоть убейте, не могу понять, зачем нужны автоматически реализуемые свойства, и в чём их принципиальное преимущество перед полями. Постоянно натыкаюсь на их использование в чужом коде - значит, преимущество всё же есть?

Просветите невежду :)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197067/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0

Comment: Исходя из прочитанного по ссылке, делаю вывод, что объявление вида string Name { get; set; } в невиртуальном классе имеет такие преимущества:

1) Вы можете установить брейкпойнт на запись или чтение свойства!

2) Свойства не хуже полей в том смысле, что вы можете заставить свойство работать так, будет это просто поле (public A { get; set; }), но вы не сможете поле заставить работать как свойство. То есть практически всегда лучше «наружу» выставлять свойство, а не поле.

3) XML-сериализация и WPF-овский Binding работают лишь со свойствами, но не с полями.

Comment: сериализация работает и с полями и со свойствами, смотря что использовать и как настроить.