# Какой смысл в применении автоматически реализуемых свойств в C#?

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

Есть класс StackOverflowTest

```
class StackOverflowTest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Какой смысл в данном примере? Да, знаю, что можно использовать модификатор доступа к аксесору, но мне важно понять именно смысл в этом примере.

Comment: Существует много библиотек которые заточены на *свойства*, а не на *поля*, потому что *свойство* можно сделать вычисляемым, а поле - нет. EntityFramework библиотека, DataGrid компонент и много других библиотек предполагают наличие *свойства*. Для обьявление свойства в NET2.0 нужно было создавать поле и свойство подвязывать к полю, поэтому придумали такое "сокращение".

Comment: @Grundy Я понимаю, зачем нужны свойства. Но мне не понятно зачем они нужны автоматически реализуемыми.

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000 Понятно что Ваш вопрос не совпадает *буквально* с тем, но ответы на тот вопрос отвечают и на Ваш. Более того, в тексте вопроса говорится именно о автореализуемом свойстве.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/548126/186999

Comment: Лучшее объяснение написал VladD [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/197075/222542)