# Для чего нужны аксессоры get и set?

Tags: c#, .net

Можете написать пожалуйста простым языком, для чего нужно в C#.NET?
Я более менее понимаю этот пример

```
public string Location
{
    get
    {
       return _location;
    }
    set
    {
       if (value != null) 
       _location = value;
    }
 }
```

Но для чего они используются в таком виде?

```
public string Make {get; set;}
public string Model {get; set;}
```

Comment: _Но для чего они используются в таком виде?_ - [справка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384054.aspx)

Comment: используются для удобства, если не нужна дополнительная логика при установки и получении значения

Answer (score 1):

Более правильным является делать публичными свойства, а не поля - так как необходимость в добавлении логики к чтению или записи, может нагрянуть весьма негаданно, а если у вас публичное поле это может вызвать проблемы. Свойство, так же, может быть определено в интерфейсе который наследует класс, а поле нет. Если класс наследует интерфейс то с большой вероятностью у вас, первоначально, будут именно такие поля.

Более подробно о различиях: [Для чего нужны свойства?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197067/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)