# Разница get; set;

Tags: c#, c#-faq

Не совсем понял разницу между

```
public object Variable1 {get; set; }
```

и

```
public object Variable1
{
    get { return this.Variable1; }  
    set {this.Variable1 = value; }   
}
```

В обоих случаях это свойство. Отличается ли не обработанные геттер и сеттер от обработанных таким образом?

Comment: Так нет разницы, это и есть реализация по умолчанию. Во второй форме вы можете изменить логику.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Для чего нужны свойства?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197067/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: во втором случае должна быть бесконечная рекурсия

Comment: Называть свойства Variable1 - нехорошо. По спецификации C# - переменные (variable) - это fields, array elements, local variables, and parameters. Свойства, события, классы, аттрибуты и прочее - это не переменные.

Comment: Хорошо. Учту на будущее.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В том виде, который привели вы, разница в том, что первый пример кода корректный, а второй - нет :) У вас во втором случае чтение свойства возвращает это же свойство, что приводит к возврату этого же свойства - и так до бесконечности. Как заметили в комментариях, это бесконечная рекурсия. Вероятно, вы имели в виду вот это:

```
private object field1;
public object Variable1
{
    get { return field1; }  
    set { field1 = value; }   
}
```

Вот в этом случае разницы нет, `public object Variable1 {get; set; }` - это автоматически реализуемое свойство, по смыслу - абсолютно тоже самое.

Comment: только `var1` закрыть бы желательно, нет?

Comment: @vp_arth ага, поправил

Comment: Извиняюсь, но не совсем понял. Раньше писал так и не совсем понял почему рекурсия. Разве геттер не возвращает само свойство?

Comment: @Leonid геттер - это метод, который выполняется при попытке прочитать значение свойства. То есть, в итоге нужно получить какое-то значение, а у вас возвращается ссылка на свойство, провоцируя выполнение геттера. Который возвращает ссылку на свойство, провоцируя выполнение геттера

Comment: Логику понял, но почему тогда работает? O_o

Comment: @Leonid Не совсем понял, что именно работает. В приведённом вами виде оно в принципе не может работать - у вас не указан тип свойства. А если указать, то не работает - я даже проверил :)

Comment: Понял. Огромное спасибо за разъяснение!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53689/discussion-between-leonid-and-eastwing).

Comment: @eastwing var1 - это поле, а не переменная. не стоит назвать поле var[iable]1 :)

Comment: @PashaPash Да мне не жалко, я переименую - но почему вдруг поле не является переменной?

Comment: хотя var1 - в любом случае неудачное название, дошло :)

Comment: @eastwing по спеке - поле является. но по ней же, например, переменными являются и параметры. спасибо, так лучше