# В чём польза рефакторинга?

Tags: c#, рефакторинг

Бывает когда пишишь код и тебе требуется улучшить его читабельность, но не всегда ясно, правильно ли это или нет!

Так вот хочу узнать у Вас, нужно ли использовать рефакторинг при написание кода?!

Допустим такой код:

```
static string Desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Студия рекомендует использовать рефакторинг, то есть инкапсулировать поле (и продолжить использовать свойства)

После рефакторинга:

```
public static string Desktop1
    {
        get
        {
            return Desktop;
        }

        set
        {
            Desktop = value;
        }
    }
```

Теперь он возвращает функцию для `Desktop`,нужно ли использовать такой подход?

Comment: Рефакторинг не используют при написании кода.

Comment: @AGS17, Да, это уже после написания)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ок, вы меня уговорили, перечислять все в комментариях не удобно, поэтому пусть будет ответом, несмотря на "холиварность" вопроса, средней степени тяжести.

**Все поля должны быть приватными.**

Это требование ООП, поэтому даже не хочу обсуждать. Если требуется предоставить доступ к полю уровня `protected`, `public` или `internal`, то использование для этого свойств обязательно.

**Когда нужны private свойства?**

В общем случае `private` свойства абсолютно бесполезны, т.к. они не могут ограничить доступ к полю - уровень доступа у них одинаковый, ниже уже некуда. Исключение составляют автоматические свойства, но их возможность ограничения доступа к полю связана не с уровнем доступа, а тем фактом, что имена полей не известны программисту, да и компилятор их генерирует только в момент компиляции.

Но один случай полезного применения приватных свойств все же есть - это вычисляемые свойства за которыми нет конкретных полей или наоборот - совокупность зависимых полей. Другой вопрос, что для этих целей можно использовать обычные методы, но тут уже нужно смотреть на семантику использования и сложность кода аксессоров.

Более подробно про преимущества свойств, когда их применять нужно, а когда не нужно можно почитать в ответе [@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) - **[Для чего нужны свойства?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/197075/198316)**

---

В приведенном вами примере, куда более ценно - явно указать модификатор `private` перед полем. Это избавит читающего ваш код от необходимости вспоминать/изучать уровень доступа по-умолчанию для членов класса.

Comment: Я правильно понял что публичные свойства лучше не использовать в том же классе, где вызывается какой-либо метод который присваивает это свойство) ? То есть это лучше использовать через другой класс и уже от туда обращаться?!

Comment: @ArteS с чего вы это взяли? Публичное свойство также может иметь вычисляемые аксесоры или содержать логику валидации, почему бы к нему не обратиться в методе того же класса, если это следует из логики метода.

Comment: в каком случае лучше не использовать аксессоры `get set`? И в каких даже очень требуется?! Поясните пожалуйста, хочу понять просто)

Comment: [Давайте продолжим в Чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--)

Comment: @ArteS ок, сейчас допишу, или найду соседний ответ =) VladD кажется уже писал об этом подробно

Comment: _Все поля должны быть приватными_ - я бы не был столь категоричным. Например, если нужна производительность, то почему бы не сделать поля публичными? [Пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix_members.aspx#Anchor_1)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я считаю, что лучше сознательно нарушать запрет, когда знаешь зачем, чем считать, что так можно делать везде. Понятно, что ради производительности, когда все уперлось именно в нее, и глобальные переменные с безусловными переходами задействовать не грех. Но тут ведь как - опытный и так знает когда без этого не обойтись и чем грозит, а новичку лучше обозначить границу, за которую ходить не надо, дорастет - поймет сам. Так что пока оставлю ответ как есть.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете это поле только внутри методов своего класса (а у вас оно приватное), то данная инкапсуляция не нужна.

Если вас интересует тема автоматического рефакторинга кода, то лучше взгянуть в сторону плагина для Visual Studio под названием `Resharper`. Он имеет бОльшую функциональность и благодаря нему новичку очень легко приучить себя писать хороший код.

Comment: Хм, но у автора до проведения авторефакторинга было всё-таки _приватное_ статическое поле, следовательно только для "улучшения читаемости" не стоит инкапсулировать это поле в свойство, изменяя при этом уровень доступа для последнего.

Comment: Я где-то вычитал что не рекомендуется использовать публичные статические поля, что для них нужно использовать публичные свойства с аксессорами `get;set;` хочу понять просто нужно ли оно или нет)

Comment: На примере у меня есть след код: `foreach (var files in new DirectoryInfo(Desktop).EnumerateFiles("",""))` но ведь правильнее же будет использовать публичное свойства например: `foreach (var files in new DirectoryInfo(Desktop1).EnumerateFiles("",""))` ?! Ваша точка зрения?

Comment: @ArteS у Рихтера хорошо написано, почему public и protected должны быть именно свойства, а не поля, это что касается технической стороны. Да и с точки зрения ООП - поля должны быть приватными, для соблюдения принципа инкапсуляции

Comment: @rdorn, Правильное ли расположения с моим примером?

Comment: @ArteS Да, вы правы! Правильно использовать именно свойство (`Desktop1`), потому как используя свойство, гарантируется то, что перед тем, как получить/установить значение приватного поля, обязательно выполнится код соответствующего аксессора. А код аксессора обычно представляет собой некоторую логику валидации данных. Если что-то непонятно, могу привести пример

Comment: @ArteS у вас исходное поле приватное (не указан ни один из модификаторов => по-умолчанию приватное) - в данном случае переход к свойству исключительно на усмотрение автора, лично я бы не стал менять, на читаемость это не повлияет никак, а время обращения, пусть и незначительно, но увеличится из-за обращения через дополнительный метод

Comment: @rdorn, И пусть обращается дольше чем обычно, но ведь пусть будет правильно чем не правильно)) Доли секунды ничего не изменят.

Comment: @ArteS а в чем правильность? ограничения доступа это не дает, от ошибок не защищает, следовательно код ради кода, а вот это уже не правильно

Comment: @rdorn - в данном случае не защищает, но тогда зачем вообще писать свойство, если можно использовать public - поле?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko первый комментарий прочитайте, у автора в вопросе приватное поле, а про публичные поля я и не говорил, это зло по определению

Comment: @rdorn я подумал, вы сейчас говорите в общем про свойства с пустыми аксессорами. Тогда да. Произошло небольшое недопонимание.