# Как исправить инициализатор свойства для VS 2013?

Tags: c#, static

Как исправить статический класс, чтобы не ругался?

Код написан для VS2017, а у меня стоит VS2013 и .NET Framework 4.5.2, соответственно я так предполагаю, что не поддерживается новый синтаксис.

Ругается на "Недопустимая лексема "=" в объявлении класса, структуры или интерфейса":

```
public static class InterpolationAlgorithms 
{ 
    /// <summary> 
    /// Canonical spline, also known as Cardinal spline. 
    /// </summary> 
    public static IInterpolationAlgorithm CanonicalSpline { get; } = new CanonicalSpline(0.5); 
}
```

Comment: что и чему вы пытаетесь присвоить?

Comment: Какая у вас версия языка? Проблема, очевидно, не в том, что класс статический.

Comment: @VladD, он уже задавал один вопрос, подобный

Comment: Библиотека написана на VS2017, а у меня VS2013 и .NETFramework 4.5.2. Соответственно такой синтаксис не поддерживается.

Comment: @Grundy: Ну не должны же все отвечающие следить за всеми вопросами?

Comment: @VladD, это мне просто совсем недавно попадался. Подозреваю будет еще несколько подобных вопросов :-)

Comment: @VladD, а у нас не было какого-то общего вопроса по новым фичам c# ? вроде было что-то подобное?

Comment: @Grundy: Это я к тому, что ТС должен бы писать эту важную информацию в **каждом** своём вопросе, не надеясь, что мы все прочитаем все его вопросы в хронологическом порядке.

Comment: @Grundy: Общего на все версии я не помню. По какой-то одной версии был.

Comment: @VladD, ну вот на тот момент последней и был, только не помню было там что-то про свойства или нет. Кстати! Может стоит обновить общий вопрос про свойства? Я про [вот этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/197075/186999)

Comment: @Grundy: Тот, который об отличиях свойства от поля? Он вроде и так перегружен, эта информация туда уже не лезет, боюсь.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте инициализировать из статического конструктора

```
public static class InterpolationAlgorithms 
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Canonical spline, also known as Cardinal spline. 
    /// </summary> 
    public static IInterpolationAlgorithm CanonicalSpline { get; }
    static InterpolationAlgorithms()
    {
       CanonicalSpline = new CanonicalSpline(0.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: присваивать значение свойствам только для чтения в конструкторе, разрешили тоже не так давно.

Comment: До такого варианта я и сама догадалась, но не работает пока что. Теперь другая ошибка: InterpolationAlgorithms.CanonicalSpline.get должен декларировать тело, так как оно не отмечено как абстрактное или внешнее. Автоматически реализованные свойства должны определять функции доступа get и set.

Comment: И еще стало ругаться на сам класс CanonicalSpline

public class CanonicalSpline : IInterpolationAlgorithm 
    
{
        
 /// <summary>
        /// The tension.
        /// </summary>
        
 public double Tension { get; }
}

CanonicalSpline.Tension.get должен декларировать тело, так как оно не отмечено как абстрактное или внешнее. Автоматически реализованные свойства должны определять функции доступа get и set.

Comment: @DHel: Ну добавьте `private set;`.

Comment: Спасибо. Скомпилилось. Буду сейчас проверять работу.

Answer (score 2):

Данный пример показывает использование инициализации свойства только для чтения.

В ранних версиях языка аналогом может служить следующий код:

```
public static class InterpolationAlgorithms 
{ 
    private static readonly IInterpolationAlgorithm  _canonicalSpline; 
    static InterpolationAlgorithms () {
        _canonicalSpline = new CanonicalSpline(0.5); 
    }
    /// <summary> 
    /// Canonical spline, also known as Cardinal spline. 
    /// </summary> 
    public static IInterpolationAlgorithm CanonicalSpline { 
        get {
            return _canonicalSpline;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Тогда уже `private static readonly`?

Comment: @VladD, конкретно в данном примере - не принципиально. Кроме конструктора это поле нигде меняется. В более общем случае оно может быть как нужным так и нет. Хотя да, идея нового синтаксиса свойства в единственной инициализации.