# Выполнить void в get/set

Tags: c#

Посоветуйте как без создания дополнительных переменных реализовать такое:

```
public int Rekt {
    get;
    set {
        Logger.Log("new Value " + value);
    }
}
```

Повторюсь, без добавления новых полей

Comment: Может без добавления дополнительных полей?

Comment: @Zergatul я думаю int это переменная...

Comment: здесь описание свойства Rekt с типом `int`. никаких переменных не используется

Comment: Ну так можно реализовать как-то что описано?

Comment: @Костя, любое авто-свойство под собой имеет поле. поэтому разницы нет, используешь ли ты поле автоматически созданное или свое. однако, обратиться к автоматически созданному полю нельзя. поэтому без ручного создания поля в данном случае не обойтись если нужен и set и get.

Comment: @Grundy мне просто нужно логирование изменение значения

Comment: @Костя, тогда придется отказаться от автосвойств

Comment: @Костя думаю, многим интересно: а зачем? В чем задумка? Размер объекта не изменяется, размер кода - больше на 1 строчку.

Answer (score 4):

Автосвойства в C# не подразумевают дополнительных операций при `get` и `set`, поэтому при их необходимости придется переходить к обычным свойствам.

```
private int rekt;
public int Rekt {
    get => rekt;
    set {
        Logger.Log("new Value " + value);
        rekt = value;
    }
}
```

Кроме этого можно воспользоваться какими-нибудь AOP решениями типа PostSharp.

Comment: не подходит такое , так как меняют rekt а не Rekt

Comment: @Костя [почитайте про свойства](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197067/Для-чего-нужны-свойства/197075#197075)

Comment: @Костя кто меняет-то?

Comment: @Костя, в окружающем коде поведение не поменяется, где-то все так же будет `obj.Rekt = val`, просто теперь будут записываться логи. Ну и как говорилось в предыдущем комментарии, поле есть и в автосвойствах, просто оно имеет специальное имя, то есть в твоем коде на самом деле меняют не Rekt, а какой-нибудь `<Rekt>k__BackingField`

Answer (score 3):

Нет, того, что вы хотите, в языке нету.

На текущий момент (C# 7.3) вы можете создать либо либо полностью автоматическое свойство, в котором несущее поле создаётся автоматически и вам недоступно, либо полностью неавтоматическое свойство, в котором несущее поле вам приходится декларировать самостоятельно.

В репозитории, посвящённом разработке и развитию языка C#, есть несколько обсуждений, в которых предлагается функциональность, близкая к тому, что нужно вам. Например, вот одно из них: [Semi-Auto-Properties; `field` keyword](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/140).