# Xamarin ListView Binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding

Не работает привязка:

C#

```
public class kek
{
    public string A;
    public string B; 
}
public partial class ListViewPage1 : ContentPage
{

    public ObservableCollection<kek> Itemsi = new ObservableCollection<kek>();


    public ListViewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Resources.Add(new ResourceDictionary(){ { "WD", App.FrameListHeight } } );

        Itemsi = new ObservableCollection<kek>
        {
            new kek { A = "n.png" , B = "cho?"},
            new kek { A = "n.png" , B = "cho?"},
            new kek { A = "n.png" , B = "cho?"},
            new kek { A = "n.png" , B = "cho?"},
            new kek { A = "n.png" , B = "cho?"},
            new kek { A = "n.png" , B = "cho?"},
            new kek { A = "n.png" , B = "cho?"}
        };

        this.BindingContext = this;

    }
```

XAML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.ListViewPage1"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp">
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          BackgroundColor="Orange"
          HasUnevenRows="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Itemsi}"
          RowHeight="{x:Static local:App.FrameListHeight}"
          ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped">

    <!--Built in Cells-->
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame x:Name="FrameFrame" Style="{x:StaticResource Style_Frame_1}" Padding="1,1,1,1">
                    <Grid x:Name="FrameGrid" Padding="0" Margin="0" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource Key=WD}"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Image BackgroundColor="LightSkyBlue" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Source="{Binding A}" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
                        <Label BackgroundColor="LightSeaGreen" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding B}"/>
                        <BoxView Color="LightGoldenrodYellow" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <BoxView Color="LightGreen" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <BoxView Color="LightPink" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        <Button BackgroundColor="LightSalmon" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Привязка возможна только к публичным свойствам!

Comment: А что из этого не публичные свойства

Comment: `public string MyString;` - знакомьтесь, поле. `public string MyString {get; set;}` - а это свойство. Теперь смотрите на эту строку `public ObservableCollection<kek> Itemsi` - что это? Да и на эти две `public string A; public string B;`. Вон можете почитать про [свойства](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/197075/220553).

Comment: Я вас понял. Благодарю