# Что такое инкапсуляция и зачем она?

Tags: c#, ооп, инкапсуляция

Только начинаю изучать `C#` и ООП, до этого дружил в основном с `python`.
Объясните непонимающему человеку, что такое инкапсуляция и зачем она конкретно?

Да, я знаю, что это объединение данных и методов в классе, сокрытие способа их работы и т. д.

Но в каких конкретно примерах она нужна, и чем опасно делать все классы и методы типа `public` если открытый код, к примеру, упрощает работу с большим проектом и в случае изменения чего-то, не нужно переписывать половину кода.

К тому же, зачастую, сама инкапсуляция увеличивает количество кода с методами `get` `set` `return`и тд., если различных переменных свыше 20-30, каждую нужно расписывать (инкапсулировать)?

Comment: Вот в том-то и дело, что если в public-штуках изменится какая-то логика, то **придётся** переписывать половину кода, потому что весь этот код нужно будет адаптировать под сделанные изменения. Если же оставить минимально возможное количество public методов и свойств, то можно попытаться сохранять их внешнее поведение максимально стабильным без значимых изменений, при этом переписывая private внутренности сколько угодно до посинения, что сильно упрощает сопровождение проекта

Comment: И кстати к python это всё тоже относится. Да в общем-то это к любому языку относится

Comment: @andreymal в python сам принцип инкапсуляции присутствует, но вот сокрытие данных, как-то не предусмотрено

Comment: https://youtube.com/watch?v=yNUJ3vAeyJQ

Comment: [Чем плоха публичность переменных в ООП?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1064142/179763)

Comment: Займитесь изучением разработки через тестирование `TDD`. И вам быстро станет понятно для чего служит инкапсуляция.