# Можно ли без каких-либо отрицательных последстий отказаться от открытых геттеров и сеттеров, если те только лишь возвращают/устанавливают значения?

Tags: java, c#, ооп, getter, setter

### Чёткое определение границ вопроса

Хотя я постарался чётко передать это в заголовке, ещё раз повторюсь, что данный вопрос сфокусирован на следующем сочетании условий:

- Геттеры лишь только возвращают значение соответствующего поля и ничего больше
- Сеттеры лишь только устанавливают новое значение соответствующего поля и ничего больше
- И геттеры, и сеттеры являются публичными

Таким образом ответы типа "сеттеры могут не только устанавливать значение, но и делать ещё что-то" или "сеттер можно сделать закрытым, тем самым сделав конкретное поле доступным только для чтения" не отвечают на заданный вопрос.

### Логическое обоснование ненужности геттеров и сеттеров для рассматриваемого случая

При обучении языкам, поддерживающих ООП, обычно говорят что-то вроде:

> Хорошим тоном является скрывать поля модификаторами `private` или
> `protected` и получать к ним доступ извне через публичные геттеры и
> сеттеры.

Насчёт того, что не следует открывать поля, которые не нужны пользователю класса, возражений нет - всё рационально. Но данный вопрос именно о тех полях, к которым нужен доступ извне. И утверждение о том, что их тоже надо делать закрытыми и добавлять к ним публичные геттеры и сеттеры, звучит как догма, бэкграунд которой неясен.

Например, такой Java-класс:

```java
class Person {

 private String name;
 private String email;

  
 public String getName() {
   return this.name;
 }

 public void setName(String newName) {
   this.name= newName;
 } 


 public String getEmail() {
   return this.email;
 }

 public void setEmail(String newEmail) {
   this.email = newEmail;
 }

}
```

отличается от класса

```java
class Person {

 public String name;
 public String email;

}
```

лишь только усложнённым способом доступа к полям `name` и `email`, но в результате пользователь всё равно может считывать и изменять это поля, потому непонятно, на каком основании часто говорят, что "с геттерами и сеттерами безопаснее".

В C#-таки вообще, существует традиция все поля обкладывать геттерами и сеттерами:

```cs
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; };
  public string Email { get; set; };
}
```

И опять: это что-то реально даёт по сравнению с ниже приведённым кодом, или просто какой-то абстрактный Best practice типа "все так делают, и ты так делай"?

```cs
public class Person
{
  public string Name;
  public string Email;
}
```

Comment: Какой то странный вопрос, ну или я не понял сути вопроса. "Скажите мне зачем нужны свойства, но то, что можно со свойствами делать не является ответом"? В [доке](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) написано, что свойства `являются специальными методами, называемыми методами доступа` - если вам они нужны - то пользуйтесь, не нужны - не пользуйтесь.

Comment: `непонятно, на каком основании часто говорят, что "с геттерами и сеттерами безопаснее"` - ну как это непоянтно, ясно же, что с геттерами и сеттерами вы общяетесь с поведением класса, при свойствах вы общаетесь с состоянием.

Comment: @tym32167, благодарю Вас за комментарии. "Скажите мне зачем нужны свойства, но то, что можно со свойствами делать не является ответом"? - Правильно так: "Скажите мне зачем нужны свойства в случае, когда и геттер, и сеттер являются публичными при этом ничего не делают кроме установки/получения значения?".

Comment: вот, доупстим, вы разрабатываете класс Person, как вы можете гарантировать, что поле Name никогда и ни при каких обстоятельствах, не будет пустым, если у вас поле публичное для записи - пиши кто хочешь и что хочешь

Comment: когда геттер и сетте не делают ничего - они своим наличием обеспечивают обратную совместимость для будущих изменений. Поля так не умеют. Ну как просто пример из головы

Comment: @tym32167 "Ясно же, что с геттерами и сеттерами вы общяетесь с поведением класса, при свойствах вы общаетесь с состоянием" - прошу прощения, но звучит слишком абстрактно. Непонятно, какую безопасность или ещё какую-либо выгоду даёт обкладка поля публичными геттером и сеттером.

Comment: [Для чего нужны свойства?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/197067/179763) - дубликат?

Comment: В своем пет-проекте вы вольны пользоваться публичными полями если вам так угодно, в более-менее серьезном проекте такой _потенциально небезопасный_ код не пройдет статический анализатор типа Сонара и/или код ревью от старших разработчиков.

Comment: @NowhereMan Благодарю Вас за комментарий. Прошу меня простить, но к сожалению, опять абстрактно: "потенциально небезопасный код", "более-менее серьезном проекте", "код не пройдет ревью". Почему конкретно небезопасно-то? Я вопрос потому и задал, что много раз слышал догмы типа: "считается хорошей практикой обкладывать поля геттерами и сеттерами", но причина этого мне непонятна.

Comment: @tym32167 уже объяснял про опасность публичного доступа к полям, в частности они могут свободно изменяться в любом другом потоке -- то есть отсутствуют гарантии определённости состояния объекта вашего класса. Геттеры/сеттеры позволяют контролировать доступ к полям и дописывать требуемую логику.  Требование поддержания единого стиля/идиом в больших проектах тоже существенно: проще сразу написать правильно, чем отлавливать баги, возникшие в результате "экономии" на написании/генерации ненавистного "нетворческого" бойлерплейтного кода. Но похоже, для вас это всё равно излишние абстракции.

Comment: [Eng SO: Why use getters and setters/accessors? 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечая коротко на ваш вопрос: можно.

Но есть одно маленькое «но». Если такой ваш код будет использоваться в другой сборке, то вы потеряете [бинарную совместимость](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).

Возможно, в будущей версии вашей программы вам всё-таки захочется воспользоваться одним из преимуществ свойств над полями (например, добавить проверку значения, навесить вызов события и т.д.) и вы обернете ваше поле в свойство, пусть даже с тем же именем. В этом случае все сборки, использующие ваш код (вашу сборку), хоть и останутся синтаксически корректными, но перестанут работать до перекомпиляции. Как ваши, так и сторонние, разработчики которых решили воспользоваться вашей сборкой.

Если же в ваших или сторонних сборках использовалась [рефлексия](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) в отношении вашего кода, то потребуется не только перекомпиляция, но и, вероятно, исправление кода.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. "В этом случае все сборки, использующие ваш код (вашу сборку), хоть и останутся синтаксически корректными, но перестанут работать до перекомпиляции." - Звучит как просто разработка и релиз новой версии библиотеки. Совершенно естественно, что когда пользователь установил новую версию зависимости, проект нужно пересобрать. Или я что-то упустил?

Comment: Рад, что мой ответ помог. По поводу релиза новой версии: если в вашей библиотеке классов меняется только тело свойств, методов и т.д., но их сигнатура сохраняется, то готовому проекту, где используются эти свойства, методы и т.д., можно, например, просто подкинуть новую версию вашей DLL. И всё будет работать без пересборки проекта. Если же вы обернете какое-то "бывшее" поле в свойство (даже сохранив имя) и подкинете новую DLL проекту, где есть обращение к этому полю, то в рантайме проекта вы получите `MissingFieldException: Field Not Found`.