# В чем разница в классе между полем и свойством?

Tags: c#, ооп, инкапсуляция

Не могу понять в книге
К переменным  невозможно получить доступ  извне, потому что по умолчанию (отсутствуют модификаторы доступа), переменные и методы создаются закрытыми и извне недоступны. Да, мы могли бы написать так:

```
class Shed
{       
   public int width;
   public int height;
}
```

Теперь переменные открыты, но никогда так не делайте. Несмотря на то, что такая  запись возможна, — это плохое программирование.

Переменные должны оставаться закрытыми (private или protected), а вот чтобы сделать их открытыми, нужно  объявить их свойства следующим образом:

```
public int Width
{       
    get
    { 
        return width;
    }

    set
    { 
        width = value;
    }
}
```

Свойства обычно создаются для того, чтобы они были открытыми, поэтому объявление начинается с модификатора доступа public. После этого идет тип данных и имя.

Т.е поля должны быть всегда private, а чтобы получить к ним доступ, нужно эти поля сделать свойствами, т.е открыть скобки и вписать туда get set? После добавления скобок поле уже становится свойством?

Comment: Если `int width;` называете "переменной", то этот термин неверен, ибо это **поле**. И да, почему это "плохое" программирование? Например, до недавних пор, все структуры были с полями.  Разница между свойствами и полями в том, что у свойств есть геттер и сеттер, которым вы можете задать нужные модификаторы доступа по отдельности, а также можете засунуть в них любую логику, которая будет выполнятся при получении значения (`get`) и/или при установке нового значения (`set`). Если ваш вопрос "в чем разница между полем и свойством", то это [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/197075/220553).

Comment: Михаил Фленов опять чудит. Поля не всегда нужно делать приватными и оборачивать свойствами. Делай так, как считаешь нужным, исходя из логики работы с классом, если поле должно быть открытым - доступным для изменения извне - делай его открытым; если нужно ограничить к полю доступ или контролировать его значение - оборачивай свойством.

Comment: @Qwer Фленов, как узнали? Причём там советы такие спецефичные, что даже будучи новичком сомневаешься в их пригодности.