# Почему я не могу менять поля структуры, если структура хранится как свойство?

Tags: c#, unity3d, .net, struct

Вопрос, конечно, *по чистому C#*. Но тег Unity3d я поставил, потому что пример оттуда.

**Есть два класса:**

```
public class A : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 vec = Vector2.zero;
    void Start()
    {
        vec.x = 10f;
    }
}

public class B : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 vec {get; set; }= Vector2.zero;
    void Start()
    {
        vec.x = 10f;
    }
}
```

Единственное отличие - свойство (get; set; структура).

Тут стоит уточнить, что **Vector2 - это структура (struct), а не класс (class)**. Vector2 имеет несколько полностью публичных (public) полей,  одно из которых - x.

В первом классе всё замечательно! Поле x у структуры Vector2 меняется на 10f и никаких ошибок. Во втором классе есть ошибка: "CS1612 Не удалось изменить возвращаемое значение 'B.vec', т. к. оно не является переменной". Я понимаю, что присутствие свойства вызывает ошибку... Но я не понимаю почему? Свойства как-то особенно работают со структурами из-за того, что они не являются ссылочными типами?

**Так вот, мой вопрос.** Почему наличие свойства "{get; set;}" (и любого другого свойства с "get"-ером) запрещает мне менять поля структуры (struct)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1747702/6808809

Comment: Не запрещает, просто геттер, будучи функцией, выдаёт вам _копию_ структуры. Которую вы меняете, но не присваиваете назад через сеттер. При работе с полем вы используете напрямую _оригинал_ структуры.

Comment: Посмотрите пример с MutableStruct [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/197075/10105).

Comment: Да, как написал @VladD, свойства это всего лишь синтаксический сахар, которые под капотом `int Value { get; set; }` превращает в самые обычные методы `int GetValue ()` и `void SetValue (int value)` и мы получаем только копию не ссылочного типа.

Comment: Попробуйте `var copy = vec; copy.x = 10; vec = copy;` или просто `vec = new Vector2(10, vec.y);`.

Comment: Использование иммутабельных структур более правильно, для них подобных проблем не возникает.